# Parsing XML file in ADF

Tags: xml, azure-data-factory

I have an XML file with one array, i wonder how i can parse this using Azure Data Factory so that all the elements are inserted in the target SQL table. I have only managed to get the first instance of OrdinaryCargo and i struggle to loop through the array. Im limited to only use ADF for this.
I would like the target table to look like this:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIdNh.png]

So one file can have many OrdinaryCargo that exixts of TransportUnit information etc.

Here is an example of the file:

````
 <Message xmlns="">
    <MessageKind>2</MessageKind>
    <MessageTimestamp>2023-09-18T15:10:35</MessageTimestamp>
    <MeasureSystem>Metric</MeasureSystem>
    <SentFrom>fj</SentFrom>
    <SentFromSystem>ca</SentFromSystem>
    <SentTo>ss</SentTo>
    <SentToSystem>PW</SentToSystem>
    <MessageId>051</MessageId>
    <Concerns>PW</Concerns>
  </Message>
  <MessageList xmlns="">
    <Voyage>
      <VoyageType>Foreign</VoyageType>
      <Arrival>
        <ArrivalDateTime>
          <ETA>
            <Date>2023-08-21</Date>
            <Time>14:10:00.0000000+00:00</Time>
          </ETA>
        </ArrivalDateTime>
      </Arrival>
    </Voyage>
    <CargoList>
      <OrdinaryCargo>
        <OC_TransportUnit>
          <TransportUnitTypeDescr>Adult</TransportUnitTypeDescr>
          <TransportUnitType>ADL</TransportUnitType>
          <TransportUnitCount>2</TransportUnitCount>
          <TransportUnitPort>HI</TransportUnitPort>
          <TransportUnitRef>117161</TransportUnitRef>
        </OC_TransportUnit>
      </OrdinaryCargo>
      <OrdinaryCargo>
        <OC_TransportUnit>
          <TransportUnitTypeDescr>Motorvehicle</TransportUnitTypeDescr>
          <TransportUnitType>CAL</TransportUnitType>
          <TransportUnitId>WES-P 80</TransportUnitId>
          <TransportUnitCount>1</TransportUnitCount>
          <TransportUnitPort>HI</TransportUnitPort>
          <TransportUnitRef>113161</TransportUnitRef>
        </OC_TransportUnit>
      </OrdinaryCargo>
      <IsLoading xsi:nil="true" />
      <SplitByBookingRefNo>false</SplitByBookingRefNo>
    </CargoList>
  </MessageList> ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To loop through the array and get all the values in the array, you can do the following settings in the mapping section.

- In Mapping settings, Click on `Import schemas`.
- Toggle on the advanced editor.
- Select the respective array value in collection reference to cross apply the value for nested XML data.
- Select and map the required fields.

[image]

**Output:**

| ArrivalDate | VoyageType | TransportUnitType | TransportUnitCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-08-21 | Foreign | ADL | 1 |
| 2023-08-21 | Foreign | CAL | 2 |